# Dark mode in multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

Is it possible to implement dark mode on multiple activities with a single toggle switch ? Or it is only possible with the help of fragments.

Please bear with me, I am new to Android development and a total beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can handle dark mode for all the fragments in your app easily like this :

```
//for dark mode
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
// for removing dark mode
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

and if you see there is no change in fragments after changing to dark mode that  is because you have defined a color in your fragment and you haven't define a color for dark mode in res>values>colors.
for this easily go to res>values>colors and there Right Click> New> values Resource Files > choose a name and in Available Qualifiers choose night mode, now you will have
a colors.xml file and
a colors.xml(night) file
which have colors with same names but different values specific for that mode(Dark/normal)

Answer (score 0):

A tricky solution is to use a static boolean variable in any of the class.
Initially,

```
public static boolean darkMode = false;
```

If the **DARK MODE** button is pressed, set

```
NameOfTheClass.darkMode = true;
```

In the onCreate() of all the activities, if **darkMode == true** then set the background color black.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the user's preferences and load them when the app is launched. For example  as a public static boolean and just call in every activity or make a CustomAppCompatActivity class which does the job for you. One way or another. You've got to be creative.